# how to check the functionality of my website without host the website? is any online service for this?

Tags: web-services, web-applications, monitoring, web-hosting

How to check the functionality of my website without host the website? is any online service for this? please help me to find the online services to check my Website Functionality before It Host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you can.You can  test your website locally.Suppose  if you are creating a  PHP website, we can use xampp control panel to test your site locally before hosting by providing url: localhost/yourwebsitefolder/phpfile. hope you got it.

Answer (score 2):

You can test your site before posting it by making an Apache server (http://httpd.apache.org/).

During installation set your domain name to localhost(or whatever you like). Then in your browser type localhost in the address bar to access your server. To access your specific content type in localhost/yourfile (localhost/folder/yourfile if your file's in a folder).

Comment: If you're not confident with this, an easier option for a newbie is Xampp.

Answer (score 0):

You can use tools like Selenium (http://docs.seleniumhq.org) to write browser automation tests to validate that your app performs as you intend.  If your site has more business logic you might want to look more into functional and integration tests that can help provide confidence in your code.